# Why my groupby.sum() pandas was not calculated?

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 different files and make it both of it with different dataframes. However, when I tried to concat the dataframes and calculate the `groupby.sum()`, the output was like this:

```py
df['total point'] = df.groupby(['submitter'])['total point'].sum()
```

Data:

```
  submitter  total_point
0   jackson            5
1   jackson           10
2    ariana            5
3    ariana            0
4     shawn           15
```

When I tried to concat and `groupby.sum()` with same dataframes, it works :(

Comment: `df.groupby(...)[...].sum()` has a different structure, e.g. length and idex, than `df`. You can't assign the former as a column of `df`.

Comment: i noticed that one of the dataframe for column name consists of " " that unable it to groupby. Thank you!